# Python : Saving changes made to an imported dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have a module itemDetails.py containing only a dictionary itemDict. I am importing this dictionary in another module named parent.py and making changes to the dictionary.

parent.py :

```
from itemDetails import itemDict

def main():
    itemDict['c'] = '3'
    itemDict['b'] = '2'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

itemDetails.py :

```
itemDict = {'a': '1', 'b': ''}
```

After parent.py has run, the module itemDetails.py remains unchanged. Is there a way to save changes?

Comment: By "save changes", do you mean rewriting the code of the `itemDetails.py` module?

Comment: If this the whole content of `itemDetails.py` you may want to consider using a `json` formatted file.

Comment: @melpomene yes i want to update the itemDetails.py

Comment: @DeepSpace I know this functionality but i think module import will be more efficient.

Comment: Why would you think so? Either way you will have to re-write the file.